# Never change the value of another component

Tags: angular

I have this service y the component:

```
export class ListUserService {
    public openMeet = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

and from the view i change this variable

```
<span> <input type="button" id="usuarios" name="more" (click)="change()"
                  value="crear Meet"></span>
```

in the component i have the function change():

```
 change() {
        this.open ? this.open = false : this.open = true;
        this.listUserService.openMeet.next(this.open);
        });
```

and i want to get the value en other component:

```
flagPerfil: boolean;
constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {
        listUserService.openMeet.subscribe((flag) => {
            this.flagPerfil = flag;
        });
    }
```

but in the view the value never change:

```
  <span>{{flagPerfil}}</span>
```

never change this value, what is the error?

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: @Reactgular help me please

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line

```
this.open ? this.open = false : this.open = true;
```

you are not changing the **`this.open`** when the click is happened, you need to change your **`change()`** method something like below

```
 change() {
     this.open = this.open ? false : true;
     this.listUserService.openMeet.next(this.open);
 };
```

I hope this will help..  :)